# how to get open source of D3 Zoomable Circle Packing from observablehq.com

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

i'm trying to do my D3 Zoomable Circle Packing responsive. I found solution in https://observablehq.com/@doub1ejack/d3-zoomable-circle-packing, but i cant use it. i have this error  :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  for   const root = pack(data)

is anyone knows how i can use it
 https://observablehq.com/@doub1ejack/d3-zoomable-circle-packing 
or which library i need to download
Thank you very much for your any answers.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the error and post some of your implementation? The more information we have the better we can help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation for Downloading & Embedding Notebooks](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks) for details about how to use Observable notebooks outside of the platform. Because Observable has specific syntax and a runtime, you'll want to use them if you embed a notebook elsewhere.